# How to remove a SKNode after a button is tapped?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have `UIButton` which when tapped once should add a `SKShapeNode` and when tapped once again should remove the same node. I have used a counter to track how many times the button is tapped. I have used `spriteScene.addChild(mySKShapeNode)` and `mySKShapeNode.removeFromParent()` to add and remove the node. This is my code:

```
  class myView: UIViewController{

  var spriteScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
  var tapCounter: Int = 0

  override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()

  . 
  .
  .

    let xPostion:CGFloat = 40
    let yPostion:CGFloat = 108
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 100
    let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 45

    button.frame = CGRect(x:xPostion, y:yPostion, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    button.setTitle("Tap me!", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.black
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myView.buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

  .
  .
  . 

    }


 @objc func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton!){

  let mySKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 270, height: 15), cornerRadius: CGFloat(5))
      mySKShapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.white
      mySKShapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 240, y: 100)

 self.tapCounter += 1
 var alternate = tapCounter / 2

   if alternate == 0{

   spriteScene.addChild(mySKShapeNode)

   } else {

   mySKShapeNode.removeFromParent()

   }

  }

 }
```

By using this code, the node gets added but it does not get removed when I tap the button again.

Comment: create your variable outside of the func buttonAction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create skshapenode outside of the function. here is the code.

```
class myView: UIViewController{

  var spriteScene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 500))
  var tapCounter: Int = 0
  var mySKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 270, height: 15), cornerRadius: CGFloat(5))
  override func viewDidLoad(){
  super.viewDidLoad()

  . 
  .
  .

    let xPostion:CGFloat = 40
    let yPostion:CGFloat = 108
    let buttonWidth:CGFloat = 100
    let buttonHeight:CGFloat = 45

    button.frame = CGRect(x:xPostion, y:yPostion, width:buttonWidth, height:buttonHeight)

    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    button.setTitle("Tap me!", for: UIControl.State.normal)
    button.tintColor = UIColor.black
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(myView.buttonAction(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    self.view.addSubview(button)

  .
  .
  . 

    }


   @objc func buttonAction(_ sender:UIButton!){


      mySKShapeNode.fillColor = UIColor.white
      mySKShapeNode.position = CGPoint(x: 240, y: 100)

 self.tapCounter += 1
 var alternate = tapCounter / 2

   if alternate == 0{

   spriteScene.addChild(mySKShapeNode)

   } else {

   mySKShapeNode.removeFromParent()

   }

  }

 }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your solution works. I knew I was making a silly mistake.

Comment: This will not create a new shape node, it will add and remove the same shape node, which may not be desired.  You most likely want to keep only a global reference, and create a new node when pressed.

Answer (score 1):

The error lies in your IBAction method

Every time you do

```
let mySKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(rectOf: CGSize(width: 270, height: 15), cornerRadius: CGFloat(5))
```

you creating a new instance of 'mySKShapeNode' .

If you want to remove the node, you need to do it on the same reference when it is added.

To do this, you need to make the 'mySKShapeNode' a global var .

If you don't want it as global var, then you can get the node by accessing the existing child nodes and find the node based on its props or give the shape node a name and you can later get it by calling

```
childNode(withName:)
```